# Can someone tell me why this wont loop?

Tags: python

I'm making a number guessing game and can someone tell me why it wont work properly?

```
import random
import time
time.time()
count=0
a = random.randint(0,100)
b = int(input("What number will you guess?"))
while b != a:
    if b > a:
        print("TOO BIG")
        count = count + 1
    elif b < a:
        print("TOO SMALL")
        count = count + 1
    else b == a:
            print("YOU WIN")
            count = count + 1
time=time.time()
print("You took",count,"tries")
print("It took you",time,"second")
```

Comment: In what way does it "not work" exactly? What is the output? What were you expecting? What have you tried so far?

Comment: you never update `b` inside of the loop. you increment count and never do anything to check if count is 10. you are better off with changing the while statement to `while 1` and then throwing an `if count == 10: break` inside of the loop somewhere, also `count += 1` is the same as `count = count + 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to accept input in the loop. Move the line b = int(input("What number will you guess?")) within the loop.

Answer (score 3):

The reason this isn't working properly is because you're calling `b = input` outside of your while loop. As it stands, the user will be asked a single time what their guess is, then the loop will just move  infinitely, because `b` is never being modified.

This loop will accomplish more what you want:

```
a = random.randint(0,100)
b = -1
while b != a:
    b = int(input("What number will you guess?"))
```

A few notes, though:

Firstly, as Lee Daniel Crocker points out, the user will actually never see "YOU WIN", because you've structured your `if-elif-else` statement incorrectly. `else` by definition cannot have a condition - it exists purely in exclusion to all other conditionals in the same block. Additionally, your else statement is the opposite of your `while` condition. When that `else` becomes true, the loop exits. You'll need to handle printing "YOU WIN" somewhere else.

Second, you're not validating the user's input in any way - if they enter 'a', the program will crash, because you can't cast 'a' to an int. Either add an exception handler (for `ValueError`) or using `isdigit()` on the string, then casting it.

Third, you're not using `time.time()` correctly - you need to subtract the time at which the user wins from the time at which they started, then represent that value, which is in seconds, in some meaningful way. As it stands you're telling each player that they took the number of seconds since the beginning of the UNIX epoch to complete the game.

Also, for usability reasons, you should probably provide the user some way to break out - a string like "QUIT" - because as it stands, the only way to restart/quit is to either close the application or `KeyboardInterrupt`.

Comment: Also, the "YOU WIN" section of code will never be reached, because it's inside the `while b != a` test.

Comment: I can't put the input in the loop as it will say that b/a variable is not defined

Comment: @lava1234567890 You'd have to define it previously - I've updated the example. -1 will never be the value, given that you're pulling your randint from 0-100.

Comment: @furkle I see what you mean and now i have fixed it. Thanks :)

Comment: @lava1234567890 If your issue is fixed, please don't forget to check one of the answers as your selected answer.

Comment: @lava1234567890 Note before you move on that I've added a few more notes - as it stand your program won't run at all.

Comment: @furkle i took on your idea and i don't really need the if-elif-else statement. I just made some slight adjustment to your code and i worked on that. http://pastebin.com/S1K1ZAH8

Comment: @lava1234567890 Cool - note that you can use `a += 1` rather than `a = a + 1`, and that you're still not using `time.time()` correctly - it doesn't store a time, or a timespan, just returns the current number of seconds since the epoch.